# Solutions for $-x=\textrm{tan}(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can the following equation be solved?

$-x=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I understand $x=0$ is one solution, but I need all of them (In particular, precisely those that are not **zero**).

Comment: There's no other solution on $(-\pi,\pi)$

Comment: This is a transcendental equation. You can only approximate the solutions numerically.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio How is there another solution on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ ? for $x\neq0$, $-x$ and $\tan(x)$ have opposite signs

Comment: @Hippalectryon, there's a countable infinity of solutions $outside$ that little interval.

Comment: @Hippalectryon, I think you mean there's no other solution on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.  If you draw the graph of $y=\tan x$ for a couple of periods, you'll see it intersects $y=-x$ at *three* points in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: W:A Gives 4 non-zero numerical solutions: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%92x%3Dtan%28x%29
Although they are not in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks, stupid mistake ;_;

Comment: @JohnWO How are they not in $\mathbb{R}$? And it actually gives more than $4$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About $r_1$:

Expressing the equation as $$\frac{\sin(x)}x+\cos(x)=0$$ and using infinite product formulas, we have 
$$f(x)\approx(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2})(1-\frac{x^2}{4\pi^2})+(1-4x^2)(1-\frac{9x^2}4),$$ not a too bad approximation close to $r_1$.

Solving the quadratic equation, we get
$$r_1\approx\pi\sqrt{\frac{205-\sqrt{21001}}{146}}\approx2.0153\cdots,$$
that we can efficiently refine with Newton.

The next order approximation still allows symbolic processing, with more complicated expressions (roots of a cubic).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form for the $n$-th root of $\tan(x)=-x$. But it can be expressed on the form of series.

Let denote $r_n$ the $n$-th root. The more $n$ is big, the more $r_{n}$ is closed to $(n-1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$. Taking account of the symetry, $r_{-n}=-r_n$ and the series expansion is of the form :
$$r_{n}=\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}+\frac{c_0}{\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}+\frac{c_1}{\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}\right)^3}+...+\frac{c_k}{\left(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}\right)^{2k+1}}+...$$
Bring back $x=r_{n}$ into the equation  $x+\tan(x)=0$ and expanding it in series of powers of $\epsilon=\frac{1}{\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}}$ allows to identify the coefficients. Well, it's a boring task ! 
$$r_{n} \simeq \frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}+\epsilon-\frac{4}{3}\epsilon^3+\frac{53}{15}\epsilon^5-\frac{1226}{105}\epsilon^7+\frac{13597}{315}\epsilon^9-\frac{65782}{385}\epsilon^{11}+\frac{478551932}{675675}\epsilon^{13}-\frac{6152345618}{2027025}\epsilon^{15}+...$$ 
$$\epsilon=\frac{2}{(2n-1)\pi}$$
valid in $n>1$ and $n<-1$

The series gives accurates values of the roots $r_2$, $r_3$, and more, but not  for the root $r_1$ because the too low convergence of the series : in the case $n=1$ the value of $\epsilon$ is too high.